How to parse a matrix of interface objects using JSON?
I have an Item interface that is used to create and store game items. These items are stored in the player's inventory in the form of a matrix (IItem[][] inventory). When trying to implement the read and write functions (translating an object into a string, and converting it), I got an error. If I create an inventory as an array of these objects, then the JSON is confused in the data types (the error code is below), I tried to create the same matrix, only from 1 specific object, without using the interface, everything works, but this is not what I need . I can conclude that the problem is in the annotations.
Error code:
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'IItem;' as a subtype of items.IItem[]: known type ids = [Diamond, Grass, Sword] (for POJO property 'inventory')
Main
import items.Grass;
import items.IItem;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Player player = new Player(new IItem[][]{{new Grass(5, 2)}},12,20);

        player.print();

        System.out.println();

        String data = player.write();
        System.out.println(data);

        System.out.println();

        Player player2 = Player.read(data);
        player2.print();
    }
}

player
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import items.Diamond;
import items.Grass;
import items.IItem;
import items.Sword;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Player {
    @JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "type"
    )
    @JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Grass.class, name = "Grass"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Sword.class, name = "Sword"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Diamond.class, name = "Diamond")
    })

    private IItem[][] inventory;
    private int health;
    private int maxHealth;

    public Player() {
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public Player(
            @JsonProperty("inventory") IItem[][] inventory,
            @JsonProperty("health") int health,
            @JsonProperty("maxHealth") int maxHealth) {
        this.inventory = inventory;
        this.health = health;
        this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Player=h" + health + ",m" + maxHealth);
        System.out.println("Inventory has:");
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < inventory[i].length; j++) {
                if (inventory[i][j] != null) {
                    System.out.print(" - ");
                    inventory[i][j].print();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String write() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
    }

    public static Player read(String data) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readValue(data, Player.class);
    }

    public IItem[][] getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }

    public void setInventory(IItem[][] inventory) {
        this.inventory = inventory;
    }

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }

    public void setHealth(int health) {
        this.health = health;
    }

    public int getMaxHealth() {
        return maxHealth;
    }

    public void setMaxHealth(int maxHealth) {
        this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
    }
}   

Item interface (IItem)
package items;

public interface IItem {
    void print ();
}

Grass
package items;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Grass implements IItem {
    public String name = "grass block";
    public int count;
    public int weight;

    @JsonCreator
    public Grass(@JsonProperty("count") int count, @JsonProperty("weight") int weight) {
        this.count = count;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(name + "=c:" + count + ",w:" + weight);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
}

Sword
package items;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Sword implements IItem{
    public String name = "sword";
    public int count, damage;

    public Sword (@JsonProperty("count")int count,@JsonProperty("damage") int damage) {
        this.count=count;
        this.damage=damage;
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(name+"=c:"+count+",d:"+damage);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public int getDamage() {
        return damage;
    }
}

Diamond
package items;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Diamond implements IItem{
    public String name = "sword";
    public int count;

    public Diamond(@JsonProperty("count")int count) {
        this.count=count;
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(name+"=c:"+count);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}

This is a test project
I tried to make annotations, but they only help in the case of 1 object, and with
a regular matrix of objects (IItem[] inventory).

You should also attach the implementation of the classes Grass, Sword and Diamond to provide a minimal reproducible example

I changed the post

I fixed it by moving the annotation from Player to the interface (IItem)
Edited IItem
package items;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Diamond.class, name = "Diamond"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Grass.class, name = "Grass"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Sword.class, name = "Sword")
})

public interface IItem {
    void print ();
}

Edited Player
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import items.IItem;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Player {
    private IItem[][] inventory;
    private int health;
    private int maxHealth;

    public Player() {
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public Player(
            @JsonProperty("inventory") IItem[][] inventory,
            @JsonProperty("health") int health,
            @JsonProperty("maxHealth") int maxHealth) {
        this.inventory = inventory;
        this.health = health;
        this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Player=h" + health + ",m" + maxHealth);
        System.out.println("Inventory has:");
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < inventory[i].length; j++) {
                if (inventory[i][j] != null) {
                    System.out.print(" - ");
                    inventory[i][j].print();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static String write(Player player) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(player);
    }

    public static Player read(String data) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readValue(data, Player.class);
    }

    public IItem[][] getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }

    public void setInventory(IItem[][] inventory) {
        this.inventory = inventory;
    }

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }

    public void setHealth(int health) {
        this.health = health;
    }

    public int getMaxHealth() {
        return maxHealth;
    }

    public void setMaxHealth(int maxHealth) {
        this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
    }
}

Result in console:
Player=h12,m20
Inventory has:
        - grass block=c:5,w:2
        - sword=c:1,d:12
        - sword=c:8

        {"inventory":[[{"type":"Grass","count":5,"weight":2,"name":"grass block"}],[{"type":"Sword","count":1,"damage":12,"name":"sword"}],[{"type":"Diamond","count":8,"name":"sword"}]],"health":12,"maxHealth":20}

Player=h12,m20
Inventory has:
        - grass block=c:5,w:2
        - sword=c:1,d:12
        - sword=c:8


Here, the object before serialization is first output, then the serialization is output, and then the desialized object from the previously output string is output
